# zend insert sql not work

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

trying to understand zf2.

my code:

```
$sql = new Sql($dbAdapter);

    $insert = $sql->insert('security');
    $insert->values(array(
            'user' => $userName,
            'ip' => '',
            'result' => 2
    ));
    $dbAdapter->query($insert->getSqlString(), $dbAdapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

error:

> Notice: Attempting to quote a value without specific driver level
>   support can introduce security vulnerabilities in a production
>   environment. in
>   /opt/projects/my/newSymbio/current/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Platform/Sql92.php
>   on line 80

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure it out.

```
$sql = new Sql($dbAdapter);

$insert = $sql->insert('security');
$insert->values(array(
        'user' => $userName,
        'ip' => '',
        'result' => 2
));
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($insert);
$results = $statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right syntax of insert in zf2:

```
   $data = array(
        ''user' => $userName,
        'ip' => '',
        'result' => '2'
    );

    $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
```

and you need to get the object of table in which table to want to insert the data.

Or another way as you are using is:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
```

Check you are using above line. And replace your last line with following code:

```
$selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($insert);
$results = $this->dbAdapter->query($selectString, $dbAdapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

And I think you need to call change the `$dbAdapter` to `$this->dbAdapter` also try this.

Comment: what is & what for tableGateway?

Comment: @Subdigger tableGateway is the object of the table that you create a time of creating the table model.

Comment: i must create table model for every 100 tables? is the any way not to use gateway?

Comment: @Subdigger Try the or part of the answer.

Comment: error comes even when i do this `var_dump($insert->getSqlString());`

Comment: @Subdigger do you have try with `$this->dbAdapter`.